# Chi-squared test with Monte-Carlo simulation in Python

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo, chi-squared

Is there a way to implement the chi-squared test with Monte-Carlo simulation in Python? The R code is shown below:

```
chisq.test(x,  
           simulate.p.value = TRUE,
           B = 2000)
```

where x is the contingency table.

Comment: Are you looking at something like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to support Monte-Carlo simulation. Do you see it?